# raw_input() does not run correctly because syntaxeror

Tags: python, syntax

I get this message when running the code:

```
Python 3.py 3.txt
I'm going to open the your file SMARTIE boy!
If you don't want that - press CONTROL_C-C
If you do want that- Press RETURN
Now i'm actually gonna do it
Now we're gonna truncate it
Write something for your beautiful day.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 19, in <module>
    line1 = raw_input("wefew")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

i don't know why

```python
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "I'm going to open the your file SMARTIE boy!" 
print "If you don't want that - press CONTROL_C-C"
print "If you do want that- Press RETURN"

raw_input = ("<3")

print "Now i'm actually gonna do it"
mission = open(filename, 'w')

print "Now we're gonna truncate it"
mission.truncate()

print "Write something for your beautiful day."

line1 = raw_input("wefew")
line2 = raw_input("fwefw")

mission.write(line1)

print "Well done! let's close the file now"
mission.close()
```

Another question - After the code run well how can I print the txt file i changed? 
Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like you are doing a beginner's tutorial in python 2. Don't. Python 2 will retire in less than 9 month and python 3 is a superior language in every regard. Dont start learning  python 2 in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

You are *shadowing* the `raw_input` function here: `raw_input = ("<3")`. That's why you cannot use the original function later on. You probably meant to just call the function:

```
raw_input("<3")
```

> Another question - After the code run well how can I print the txt file i changed?

Open the file again, read and print the contents.

Suggestion: try reading about the [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) concept that handles opening and closing file objects for you:

```
with open(filename) as textfile:
    print(textfile.read())
```

Comment: I think he's using Python 2.

Comment: @youssef Yes, I would also assume that, based on the `print`s. But what are you suggesting with your comment? I'm quite sure everything in my answer works in Python 2. The context manager was introduced in Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know that this is working in Python 2 as well.